# NgModel on custom component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple component which I include in my form like this:

```
<app-slider [min]="field.min" [max]="field.max" [value]="field.min"></app-slider>
```

The component is the following:

html:

```
<input #mySlider
       class="slider"
       type="text"
       name="slider"
       data-provide="slider"
       data-slider-min="1"
       data-slider-max="3"
       [attr.data-slider-min]="min"
       [attr.data-slider-max]="max"
       data-slider-step="1"
       [attr.data-slider-value]="value"
       data-slider-tooltip="show"/>
```

ts:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';

declare var $ : any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-slider',
    templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent{
    @ViewChild('mySlider') slider: any; // can be ElementRef;
    @Input() min: number;
    @Input() max: number;
    @Input() value: number;

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // slider is available
        $(this.slider.nativeElement).slider();
        let value = $(this.slider.nativeElement).attr("data-slider-value");
        $(this.slider.nativeElement).slider('setValue', value);
    }
}
```

I'd like to add NgModel on my component so I can get and change his value:

```
<app-slider [min]="field.min" [max]="field.max" [value]="field.min" [(ngModel)]="currentValue"></app-slider>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
<app-slider [min]="field.min" [max]="field.max" [(value)]="currentValue"></app-slider>
```

change the value of `currentValue` using `changeCurrentValue`

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

declare var $ : any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-slider',
    templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent{
    @ViewChild('mySlider') slider: any; // can be ElementRef;
    @Input() min: number;
    @Input() max: number;
    @Input() value: number;
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
         let self = this;
        // slider is available
        $(this.slider.nativeElement).slider();
        let value = $(this.slider.nativeElement).attr("data-slider-value");
        $(this.slider.nativeElement).slider('setValue', value);

       $(this.slider.nativeElement).slider().on('change', function(event) {
          self.value = event.value.newValue; self.valueChange.emit(self.value); });
          }

   changeCurrentValue(){
      this.value= //some value;
      this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
   } 
}
```

Comment: I've just wrote almost the exact same code with ssougnez answer but I use a jquery method to get updates from the slider    
    `$(this.slider.nativeElement).slider().on('change', function(event) {
 this.value = event.value.newValue;
 this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    });`
Problem is, I get an error when the value changes. The EventEmitter variable is undefined: `Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined`. I know it's not related to the two way databinding. But do you think it is due to the ngAfterViewInit method?

Comment: @Servietsky see the update, don't use `this` inside the `on` function

Comment: You could also use the fat arrow operator to avoid mismatches with this, couldn't you?

Answer (score 4):

Foreword: it looks like you use sth like jquery ui slider but bit different. In places where I had to assume sth I used its api.

Basically thing which you want to do I did through implementing `ControlValueAccessor` to make component recognized by ng as form control or in other words custom form control. Not sure whether syntax is up to date with latest ng approaches but mine used to look as follows:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Input, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

declare var $: any;

export const SLIDER_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => SliderComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    selector: 'app-slider',
    templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css'],
    providers: [
        SLIDER_VALUE_ACCESSOR
    ]
})
export class SliderComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @ViewChild('mySlider') slider: any; // can be ElementRef;
    @Input() min: number;
    @Input() max: number;

    propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
    propagateTouched = () => { };

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // slider is available
        $(this.slider.nativeElement).slider();
    }

    onChange() {
        this.propagateChange($(this.slider.nativeElement).attr("data-slider-value"););
    }

    /**
     * Write a new value to the element.
     */
    writeValue(value: any): void {
        $(this.slider.nativeElement).slider('setValue', value);
    }

    /**
     * Set the function to be called when the control receives a change event.
     */
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.propagateTouched = fn;
    }

    /**
     * This function is called when the control status changes to or from "DISABLED".
     * Depending on the value, it will enable or disable the appropriate DOM element.
     *
     * @param isDisabled
     */
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        // it would look like this if jQuery UI slider was used
        $(this.slider.nativeElement).slider(isDisabled ? "disable" : "enable");
    }
}
```

Template like:

```
<input #mySlider
    class="slider"
    type="text"
    name="slider"
    data-provide="slider"
    data-slider-min="1"
    data-slider-max="3"
    [attr.data-slider-min]="min"
    [attr.data-slider-max]="max"
    data-slider-step="1"
    data-slider-tooltip="show"
    (change)="onChange" /> <!-- change event as in jQuery UI slider  -->
```

and usage as:

`<app-slider [min]="field.min" [max]="field.max" [(ngModel)]="currentValue"></app-slider>`

and `currentValue` has to initialized with `min` value to work as it seems to work in example.